# Installing GDAL2.1

Tags: python, gdal, installation

Here will be my sequence of command lines while trying to install gdal2.1 in a UBUNTU virtual machine. My virtual machine is a UBUNTU 16.04 LTS(64bit) I would need gdal2.1 and especially the Python bindings to work with it in python. The versionof python currently working is 2.7.11+ and I installed numpy as I know that it is necessary for GDAL.
now the command lines with the instruction I found in the Pypi page of GDAL2.1:

antonio19812@antonio19812-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install libgdal1i

Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto

Generazione albero delle dipendenze

Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto

libgdal1i is already the newest version (1.11.3+dfsg-3build2).

0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 62 non aggiornati.

antonio19812@antonio19812-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev

Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto

Generazione albero delle dipendenze

Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto

libgdal1-dev is already the newest version (1.11.3+dfsg-3build2).

0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 62 non aggiornati.

antonio19812@antonio19812-VirtualBox:~$ sudo pip install gdal

Collecting gdal
  Downloading GDAL-2.1.0.tar.gz (619kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 624kB 247kB/s

Installing collected packages: gdal

Running setup.py install for gdal ... error

```
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
```

tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-_sHDUY/gdal/setup.py';

exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n',

'\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-eOB65J-record/install-

record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying gdal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying ogr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying osr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying gdalconst.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
copying osgeo/gdal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
copying osgeo/gdalconst.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
copying osgeo/osr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
copying osgeo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
copying osgeo/ogr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
copying osgeo/gdal_array.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
copying osgeo/gnm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
copying osgeo/gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
running build_ext
building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extensions
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extensions/gdal_wrap.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3085:22: fatal error: cpl_port.h: File o directory non
```

esistente

```
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-_sHDUY/gdal/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-eOB65J-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_sHDUY/gdal/

This was what I obtained. Consider that the VM has not other software or packages installed. I hope you can help me, using GDAL2.1 would be so important..

Comment: @Luke, please consider adding your comment as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.

Comment: Ah yes, the [Python 2.8 un-release (PEP 404)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/).

Comment: ok now I will provide the sequence of command line in my virtual machine. I prefer to work with a VM because I want to work in linux while my OS is Windows8.1 and I do not want to modify nothing on it.

Answer (score 25):

You can download GDAL 2.1 for Windows from [GIS Internals](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php). There is an installer and a portable version that doesn't require installation.

[GDAL 2.1](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=xenial) is available for Ubuntu 16.04 from the [UbuntuGIS-Unstable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable)

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade # if you already have gdal 1.11 installed 
sudo apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal # if you don't have gdal 1.11 already installed
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You have GDAL 1.11.3 installed, and the repository you want to install from does not provide a newer package. So you have to add another resource, that has a GDAL 2.1 package. Like the Ubuntugis-unstable PPA.

Comment: yes I have libgdal-dev 1.11.3 and libgdal 11.3 , that could be the reason?

Comment: @Antonio Don't use pip. Just add the ubuntugis-unstable PPA and upgrade. Also make sure you have python-gdal installed for python 2.7 support or python3-gdal for python 3.4 support

Comment: Great solution. I can import gdal using python 2 using this approach, but not python 3. Any suggestions on installing gdal with the python3 bindings?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Check that the `osgeo` package gets installed to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` when you `apt-get install python3-gdal` and check that /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages is in your python path (and that you installed `gdal-bin`;)   I don't have access to 16.04 anymore (unless I build a vm/docker) so can't test.  But I've pretty much stopped using system package managers and just maintain identical conda envs that "just work" (tm) on my Windows and various Linux environments.