# gdal_merge.py not found

Tags: raster, qgis-plugins, ubuntu, gdal-merge

I'm newbie with Linux and QGIS. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and QGIS 3.0 Girona and I can't do mosaic from a raster pile because the following log error message returns:

```
 Processing algorithm… AlgorithmDialog Input parameters: { 'DATA_TYPE'
 : 2, 'INPUT' : '', 'NODATA_INPUT' : 0, 'NODATA_OUTPUT' : 0, 'OPTIONS'
 : '', 'OUTPUT' :
 '/tmp/processing_b9cc3491592e4af584caddae75abe2cf/d6cd346d9c534b2a9bb38c222bbc6cf4/OUTPUT.tif',
 'PCT' : False, 'SEPARATE' : False }

 GDAL command: gdal_merge.py -n 0 -a_nodata 0 -ot UInt16 -of GTiff -o
 /tmp/processing_b9cc3491592e4af584caddae75abe2cf/d6cd346d9c534b2a9bb38c222bbc6cf4/OUTPUT.tif
 --optfile /tmp/processing_b9cc3491592e4af584caddae75abe2cf/mergeInputFiles.txt
 GDAL command output: /bin/sh: 1: gdal_merge.py: not found

 Execution completed in 0.02 seconds Results: {'OUTPUT':
 <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition
 {'sink':/tmp/processing_b9cc3491592e4af584caddae75abe2cf/d6cd346d9c534b2a9bb38c222bbc6cf4/OUTPUT.tif,
 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}
```

I presume that the gdal_merge.py isn't installed or activated. How can I fix this problem?

OBS.: Maybe other GDAL functions have the same problem, but I have not tried yet.

Comment: How are you calling GDAL_Merge? It's a python script, not an executable, so it needs more system paths set; I'm not sure how to do that in Linux but it's looking for the script file and can't find it so your search path needs to be updated; on Windows QGIS is started by a script (batch file) that sets the system paths, you may need to find your QGIS script and edit it so that it can locate the merge script and also python and GDAL python bindings.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify how you installed QGIS 3.

Comment: Luke, I followed the instructions of this page: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu

Comment: In the sources list I added these two lines: deb https://qgis.org/debian bionic main and
deb-src https://qgis.org/debian bionic main. Next, I followed these steps: sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass. As apparently there were no keyserver errors, so I stopped at these steps.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and probably used the same installation procedures. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: UPDATE. Installing this seemed to fix the problem (now I'm getting a memory error, but that's probably unrelated): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193814/installing-gdal2-1/193828#193828

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem on QGIS 3.10 on LinuxMint/Ubuntu 18.04

```
/bin/sh: 1: gdal_merge.py: not found
```

I solved this issue by installing the additional package: **python-gdal**

```
 sudo apt install python-gdal
```

Comment: This solution seems to be obsolete. I get the following message:
```Package python-gdal is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

However the following packages replace it:
  gdal-bin

E: Package 'python-gdal' has no installation candidate```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem in Fedora and I solved it by installing `gdal-python-tools` (`python-gadl` does not seem to provide `gdal_merge.py`)

Comment: Unable to locate package gdal-python-tools; It's not working. I have updated the repo but still get the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I forgot to mention that I was using Fedora. I edit it already

Comment: Also works for me on Fedora 38 and QGIS 3.28.10-Firenze

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:

`apt install gdal-bin`

Test it by simply typing `gdal_merge.py` on the terminal and it'll show you how to use the utility.

Comment: Just saying that repeating the question in the answer as well as stating that the other answers dont work for you is not necessary ;)

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu go to synaptic and install python-gdal and python3-gdal

Comment: Welcome to the GIS Stack Exchange site, thank you for providing an answer to an unanswered question. When providing an answer please try and include as much information as possible to allow for someone to follow the instructions given. Please take the tour: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour of the site it will provide some guidance on how best to provide an answer.